# If $p^2=p=pq$ and $q^2=q=qp$, then $p=q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is probably something that is so obvious to many of you but I am having a hard time answering it.

> **Question:** If $R$ is a non-commutative ring and $p$ and $q$ are non-trivial idempotents satisfying $p=pq$ and $q=qp$, does it follow $p=q$?

Clearly if $R$ is commutative, the answer is trivial. At least by purely straightforward algebraic manipulation, I can't seem to get the asserted equality. Perhaps there is a counterexample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ in $M_2(\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: The upshot of this is that an idempotent generator of a left ideal doesn't have to be unique.